# Firebase extension "Send Messages with Twilio" not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, twilio, twilio-api, firebase-extensions

I create a document in the `messages` collection, and I get a delivery response which shows the status `SUCCESS`, but I never get any SMS from Twilio.

[image]

This is the Twilio Console error
(11200):

[image]

I googled this and the only solution I found was to disable SSL Certificate Authorization, I did so but it still gets the same error. Please help.

Comment: Hi! It seems like the SUCCESS is indicating the message was successfully sent and wouldn’t be related to response information from our REST API. I could be wrong there.
If you provide the Notification SID (NOxxxx) from the 11200 error or the Message SID (SMxxxx), someone from the Programmable Messaging team might be able to troubleshoot further. I imagine that if you're experiencing message deliverability issues it’d be better suited for a ticket as the Messaging Team may need to get information from the carrier.

Comment: @lizziepika I created a support ticket, here is my Message SID: SM2ab21c48be8ab8c0ad3479c7a7d163f7. Thank you for your response.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21608 I think the person using the extension just needs to upgrade their account

Comment: @lizziepika Yes you are right, that's what support said yesterday, however the story is more complex it seems. My friend had paid for the upgrade and it hasn't registered in the account yet. He has responded to the ticket, I hope it gets sorted.